# Get page title of a native app using appium

Tags: java, ios, appium

It doesn't seem that appium now has a direct way to get and verify the page title of a native app, similar to the way it works on a web using the `driver.getTitle();` method. Is this correct?

An indirect way I am using is the `driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getText();` method on the page header text and then assert that the text is correct. With this method, there is no proof that the text fetched is definitely the title of the page as the text could also be contained in any part of the page.

Has anyone got a more genuine way of getting and verifying the page title of an iOS native app?

Comment: Have you tried [appium desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop)? There is a utility tool, the inspector, that you could use to get the xpath expression you need to pass to the `By.xpath()` method.

Comment: @lalongooo, it's not about the inspector or inspection of elements, it about the code required to get the title of a page in native app. I already use xpath method for identifying elements